# How do you correct a mistake on the UK Visa application?

Tags: visas, uk

Under "Travel And Criminal History" I answered the question "25. Have you been issued any visa for the UK, UK Overseas Territories or Commonwealth Country in the last 10 years?" in the negative.

However, I have been to Singapore & Malaysia (Commonwealth countries) and have mentioned the travel details under foreign travel. How do I make this error known to the relevant authorities?

**Update:** The student immigration office at my university has asked me to attach a cover letter that mentions these details. Whom should I address this to?

Comment: Is everything there except the yes/no box? And has the fee already cleared your account?  It may be helpful to know which VFS is handling the application and when your appointment was also.

Comment: The appointment is in a few days at the New Delhi office of VFS Global. I do not have the visa details of these travels as they have been misplaced. However, travel details are in the old passport.

Comment: Easy. When you print out the form, make a pen correction to cross out the 'no' box and check the 'yes' box.

Comment: Okay. I have also been asked to attach a cover letter. Whom should I address it to?

Comment: See the linked question and you'll be fine